# Representing an equation with a simulation of Operation amplifier adder

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation

I am trying to represent an equation (Vf=-3V1+7V2+2) using operation amplifiers. The schematic that I did is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq0GGt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but I have troubles simulating it and doing it in reality. The problem is that when instead of putting two operation amplifiers, I put two source of voltage and its resistances like in V7, it gives me the correct answer, but when I put operation amplifiers, it gives an unwished answer

Using Op Amps
[image]

Not Using Op Amps
[image]

Have you got any idea why is this happening?, I believe that the equations are right because I obtain in both diagrams the input voltage that I want, but the problem is the output. I would appreciate any ideas you have, thanks in advance

Comment: The voltage level is consistent up to U1B +input at 3.146V. The output is 3.14V. Perhaps U1B is working like an unity buffer, which would be the case if R5 is not connected. R5 does have an extra blob on its pin, I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that for the middle input, without the opamp, v=14v, and with the opamp, v=13.5v.

TL084 outputs don't go to the rails, so with 15v supplies, the output stops short of where it should be.

Use an opamp with a R2R output, or increase the supply voltage, or decrease your test voltages so that all internal voltages are within the linear range of your amplifiers.

Comment: Sorry, I still have problems. I didn't put the TL084 output to the rails, I don't understand what do you mean by that. I tried to increase the Supply Voltage to 170 V and it gives me the answer I need, but the problem is that the adder is wrong because the last op amp increase and also I don't believe that could support that voltage. My test voltages were 2 Volts all, now they are 1 Volt, but still the adder doesn't add correctly. My simulation is: [http://codinglife.esy.es/adder.pdsprj]

Comment: A TL084 cannot drive its output closer than 1.5v to the +ve rail, that's why the voltage at the input to R6 is 13.5v, while the voltage at R13 is 14v.

Comment: but still the adder should add with those voltages values, isn't? How can I fix it?. I can't put neither a 170 Voltage source nor less than 1 volt in the test volts

Comment: @Delfin: use a voltage divider to reduce the applied test voltages. You could then put a buffer stage after the dividers to not load the circuit.